# Stop inserting newline before comma

Tags: bash, macos-catalina

I have a bash script running on MacOS Catalina. The script appends lines to a csv file, but something seems to be inserting new lines before the comma.

In the script, when I successfully complete a step, I want to log this in the csv by adding the id and the word "success".

```
log=results.log
id=474651680

echo $id,success >> $log
```

I want the file to contain:

```
474651680,success
```

But instead the file contains:

```
474651680
,success
```

I can't figure out why this newline is being inserted.

Comment: I'll make a wild guess and say that `id` actually contains a newline. If you run the script, as you show it in the question, there should be no newline in the log file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's definitely a newline in `id`

Strip it using bash's ["suffix removal"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) and ["ANSI-C quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) features:

```sh
echo "${id%$'\n'},success" >> $log
```

Explanation:

- `${id}` same as `$id`
- `$'\n'` converts the string `"\n"` to newline
- `${id%suffix}` outputs `$id` with `suffix` removed

Comment: This was a very clear comment, thank you. It turns out that I had \r in my variable, not \n, but everything else worked exactly like you suggested. To figure out what non-printable characters were in there, I used `echo $myvar | cat -ve`, which showed I had a ^M suffix, which turned out to be the \r character. I just used `${id%$'\r'}` to remove it as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```sh
set -e # exit on erro
set -x # show debug level info in console
```

You will then be able to see what's going on behind the scenes when running your script in the terminal.

Also try using: `"${variableName}"` rather than just `$variableName`

In your case I'd try:

```sh
echo "${id},success" >> $log
```

Also it seems likely there's a new line being included as part of the variable you're setting as `id`. Chances are it could be your editor doing this.

Comment: Thanks the set command seem generally very useful.